# Using Jquery Widgets on Drupal

Tags: 6, javascript

Hello i was hoping to make some of my blocks accordian style.
[JQUERY ACCORDIAN WIDGET](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#default)

I know there is a module for this but that only does whole block regions and i was looking at styling individual blocks. Also the module doesnt seem to work too well for me so anyhows...here we be.

I followed intructions from this page-
[jquery accordian d6](http://cleaver.ca/content/jquery-ui-accordion-drupal-6)

Ive got jquery update going and i can see i have version 1.3.2

I have added

```
jquery_ui_add('ui.accordion');
```

to my template.php. Then i added-

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion();
});
</script>
```

to my page.tpl. and then added this (as a test) around my right hand sidebar (although i would like to put it around individual blocks but i think i would just add this to block.tpl (for each block)

```
 <div id="accordion"><?php print $sidebar_second; ?></div>
```

When i view my page which you can view here-
[My website](http://onlinebanter.com)

i see that everything seems to be in order, i think, but no accordian behaviour. I will go and start adding the css to my block.tpl's.

Can anyone see where i am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: update- ive added the accordian just to one block, the science links block that you can see on the right here- http://onlinebanter.com/science still no accordian effect though.

Comment: hey you want to make the entire block to do accordion effect or the items inside sidebar second block area?

Comment: individual blocks Aboodred please :) ive added code to block-views-weblinks-block_1.tpl.php which looks like <div id="accordion">
  <?php if ($title): ?>
    <h3 class="title"><?php print $title; ?></h3>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <div class="content">
    <?php print $content; ?>dddd
  </div>

  <?php print $edit_links; ?>
</div><!-- /.block -->

Comment: oh i must mention i changed the h2 to h3 in the block to see if it was maybe just working for h3 and the dddd was just me seeing if my tpl overide had worked

Comment: You need to add additional header and content after header to make the accordion effect work

Comment: e.g. <h3>header1</h3><div>content</div><h3>header2</h3><div>content</div>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7468/discussion-between-aboodred1-and-reg-gordon)

Comment: ah i see Aboodred tx. I think i was just wanting to make the block collapsible possibly then. Ok lets go back to making the hole region accordian then as that could still work for me. errrr

Comment: actually no i was wanting individual collapsing blocks truth be told Aboodred. Maybe the accordian is not for me. I will look for something else.... (thats not drupal collapsible block module as that doesnt work for me)

Comment: arrrrghhhh this is driving me mad. Ive reverted back to collipsible block module and that doesnt seem to want to work either. im going mad here. ive pulled all my hair out. <div data-collapsed="true" data-role="collapsible">
<h2 class="title">science Links</h2>
<div class="content">
<div class="edit">
</div>

Comment: heres a screenshot of my selectors http://s9.postimage.org/xy760yyrz/coll.jpg i just dont know whats going on.

Comment: Im slowly getting there i think. I know we are now taling about the collapible block module and not jquery. If i change my selectors to .section, .block h2.title, .block .content i can get the first block in my sidebar collapsed. if i change section to .block or .block class i get nothing.